# How does fork() stop creating children?

Tags: c, fork

Can anyone explain me how this works?

if I have in my code something like

```
int pids[N];
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    pids[i] = fork();
    if(pids[i]==0){
        //do something
        break;
    }
}
```

Wouldn't I be creating N children and then in each child N children again and end up in a loop?

Comment: Of course not, because the children `break` the loop...

Comment: in general, it is best for 'child' code to end in `exit()`  However, in the current scenario, the 'break;' statement will exit the `for()` loop, but then every child process will be executing the code following the `for()` loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From http://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4411.ck/www/NOTES/process/fork/create.html (emphasis mine):

> After a new child process is created, **both processes will execute the next instruction following the fork() system call**.

So, `fork()` creates a child, and the child does not start from the beginning of the loop: it starts from the instruction after the call to `fork`, that is,  from `if(pids[i]==0){`, which for the child is true. Then it will *do something*, and then `break`. Break means that it exits the `for` loop, thus the child does not create any more processes.

So, the father creates N children, whereas each child does the work and breaks from the loop without creating any more children.

Answer (score 4):

> Wouldn't I be creating N children

Yes.

> and then in each child N children again

No, why? Every child process executes `break;` and leaves the loop. No further processes are created.

> and end up in a loop?

Even if you didn't have that `break;` in there, every child would just execute the rest of the `for` loop. It wouldn't restart from `i = 0`. That means in every iteration the number of processes would double, so you'd end up with `2^N` processes total. But with that `break;` it's just plain `N`.